# Focus browser position on toggled block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few ul blocks and buttons that open up their content. When i press the button - block goes down with all content in it, but screen stays focused. But when I scroll down to the bottom of the block and press the button to toggle it back to hide mode - the browser screen moves down to the bottom of browser and doesnt go back to the top of closed block (as expected)

```
$('.ul' + l).append('<button type="button" onclick="$(this).myFunc()">Button</button>');

           $.fn.myFunc = function () {
           var ul = $(this).parent().attr('class');
           $('.' + ul + ' li:gt(5)').fadeToggle("fast");
                        };
```

I tried to et some `$(window).focus` stuff, added `fadeToggle("fast").preventDefault()` etc, but nothing helped. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `l` in `$('.ul' + l)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "screen stays focused"?  It sound like you're trying to control the scroll position, for which you need `window.scroll()` or `$(...).animate({scrollTop, ...}`, not focus.

Comment: @Akshay Sorry I didnt mention it before - it is just an for-loop iterator for quantity of blocks to build

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes i need my scroll position to be on the top of block after toggle it back by clicking button. And I would like you to help me a little bit more to write what you did but with my code too. Because I also tried to implement this window.scroll() and nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you need is the native `scrollIntoView()` method:

```
document.querySelector('.ul' + l).scrollIntoView({ 
    behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

This is supported in [current versions](http://caniuse.com/#search=scrollintoview) of all major browsers, but if you need support for older browsers (IE 10 and below for example) you can use this [polyfill](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/).

Per the comments below: you do have a `document` object, I promise: `document` underlies every web page.  That said you can use a jQuery selector instead, if you want, but you need to  get the underlying DOM object before you can use `scrollIntoView` (because it's not a jQuery method.)

```
$('.ul' + l)[0].scrollIntoView({...});
```

Comment: Thank, but as i do not have a document and do everything in script I wrote (incorrect) this:
   `$.fn.myFunc = function () { var ul = $(this).parent().attr('class'); `
   `$('.' + ul + ' li:gt(5)').fadeToggle("fast").scrollIntoView( {`                     `behavior: 'smooth'});  };`
And it throw an error in console `scrollIntoView is not a function`

Comment: You do have `document`, every page does, but I've updated the answer to show how to convert from a jquery object as well.